# Express 4 - Custom error handling middleware is not being called

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware

I am trying to implement a custom error handler in my Express app. I think I am following the docs correctly, but I must be doing something wrong, because my app is returning HTML any time an endpoint errors out.

Docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Pretty much every similar issue I have found here and on GitHub has been resolved by placing the error handling middleware and the very end of the stack... but I have already done that, and still no luck.

Here is my code:

// server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import body from 'body-parser';
import cookies from 'cookie-parser';
import {
    provideLogger,
    responseStructure,
    errorHandler, // => confirmed is importing the right function
} from '@middleware';
import routes from '@routes';
import { Logger } from '@utils';
import config from '@config';

const logger = new Logger().context('startup');

async function onAppReady(...args) {
    logger.success(`API listening on port ${config.port}`);
}

express()
    .use(body.json())
    .use(cookies())
    .use(provideLogger)
    .use(responseStructure)
    .use(routes)
    .use(errorHandler) // => applied after routes
    .listen(config.port, onAppReady);
```

// routes.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import myRoute from './myRoute';

const router = new Router();

router.use('/route', myRoute);


export default router;
```

// myRoute.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import endpoint from './endpoint';

const myRoute = new Router();

myRoute.post('/:objectId/', endpoint);


export default myRoute;
```

// endpoint

```
export default function endpoint(req, res, next) {
  console.log('I am an endpoint, time to trigger an error');
  next({ status: 404, message: 'Success not found :(' });
}
```

// middleware

```
export function errorHandler(
  {
    error = {},
    message = 'An error occurred.',
    status = 500,
  } = {},
  req,
  res,
  next,
) {
  console.log('I am handling the error');
  res.status(status).send({ error: true });
}
```

When I send a request to the endpoint, it prints the log from my endpoint, then returns an HTML file with the data I passed into `next` as the HTML body. The log from my errorHandler is never printed.

I have poured over the docs, and from what I can tell, I'm doing everything right. I have to be missing something, but what?? Why is my error handler never being called??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with the way I was setting the default value for the first argument in the error handler.

Changing from

```
export function errorHandler(
  {
    error = {},
    message = 'An error occurred.',
    status = 500,
  } = {},
  ...
```

to

```
export function errorHandler(
  {
    error = {},
    message = 'An error occurred.',
    status = 500,
  },
  ...
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please, note if you use async handler for the endpoint throwing an error e.g.

```
app.get('/uri', async (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('dummy error');
});
```

you should use [express-async-errors](https://github.com/davidbanham/express-async-errors#readme)